# Css: does repeating the same class on an element change any behavior?

Tags: html, css

Mostly out of curiosity, I would like to know if there are any edge cases that can arise from cases like:

```
<span class="class1 class2 class3 class2 class4">...</span>
```

(`class2` is listed twice)

or

```
<span class="class1 class2 class3 class2 class2 class2 class3 class4 class4 class3">...</span>
```

(a more extreme version of the same)

This is obviously messy css and not ideal, but **are there any edge cases this creates?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, none whatsoever**, unless you have the habit of using the `class` attribute:

```
[class="class1 class2"] {
    /* ... */
}
```

instead of:

```
.class1.class2 {
    /* ... */
}
```

which is terrible practice, of course.

---

Also, although your question isn't tagged [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), note that if only the first instance of a class is removed and an unlimited number added, say:

```
function addClass(element, cls) {
    element.className += ' ' + cls;
}
```

but

```
function removeClass(element, cls) {
    return element.className.replace(cls, ' ');
}
```

this will cause problems in more ways than one.

Answer (score 1):

FYI

browsers such as firefox/chrome/ie9,

**computing the style contexts using the rule tree**,

**if two rules have the same weight, origin and specificity, the one written lower down in the style sheet wins**. so ...

styles :

```
.c1 {background:red;}.c1.c3 {background:blue;}.c2 {background:orange;}
```

case1 :

```
<div class="c1 c1 c1"/><!-- background is red -->
```

case2 :

```
<div class="c1 c2"/><div class="c2 c1 c2"/><!-- background is orange -->
```

case3 :

```
<div class="c2 c1 c1 c2 c3"/><!-- background is blue -->
```

Comment: That's not true; it's the "Cascading" part of Cascading Style Sheets. Specificity takes priority, with order soon following. (And of course, the order of the classnames in the `class` attribute doesn't matter.)

Comment: "the order of the classnames in the class attribute doesn't matter." this's the sample want to show :) @minitech

Comment: Oh, okay. The way you said it is a little confusing, though. The values aren't sorted.

Comment: then how do you explain class="c1 c2" and class="c2 c1" has the same background color orange :) @minitech

Comment: The same way that I explain that [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/NeLsS/1)'s background is orange and not blue, yet the paragraph is red - specificity. Here's a good article for you to read: http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/

Comment: Ty @minitech. if two rules have the same weight, origin and specificity, the one written lower down in the style sheet wins.

Comment: Yes. *In the stylesheet.* No sorting of the attribute is performed.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing *wrong* with it other than it looks weird. Any re-occurences of a class name won't affect anything, ever. It doesn't "reapply" those styles after applying styles from the class defined before it or anything. Remember that CSS will always select the style defined *last* for that level of specificity.

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xZmvX/2/) and note how class4 *always* overrides the font color, no matter what combinations of class1, class2, and class3 are used.

Ultimately, it's seen as having class name class1, having class name class2, having class name class3, and having class name class4. Repeating them is like clicking on the radio button again. It's already selected, no need to keep clicking it...